# Populating a table with data from a plist

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swift, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I'm populating a table from a plist following a Ray Wenderlich tutorial that was coded in Objective C. I'm struggling to convert the following code from Objective C to Swift:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
     NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
     NSArray* sortedCategories = [self.articleDictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

      NSString *categoryName = [sortedCategories objectAtIndex:section];

      NSArray *currentCategory = [self.articleDictionary objectForKey:categoryName];

return [currentCategory count];
}
```

When I convert as follows:

```
var sortDescriptor:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: nil, ascending: true, selector: "localizedCompare:")
```

I'm getting a compiler error stating "Extra argument 'selector' in call

And then when I attempt the following line I get XCode suggesting I use:

```
let sortedCategories:NSArray = [articleDictionary.allKeys.sort(<#isOrderedBefore: (AnyObject, AnyObject) -> Bool##(AnyObject, AnyObject) -> Bool#>)]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with passing nil for the key, despite the error message that you're getting (Swift's error messages aren't so swift). If you don't need a key, then you should use sortedArrayUsingSelector: instead,

```
let keys: NSArray = articleDictionary.allKeys
var sortedCategories = keys.sortedArrayUsingSelector("localizedCompare:")
```

It also seems to work if you pass an empty string (rather than nil) for the key parameter to sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:selector: